# What should be the metrics returned from protractor-perf getStats method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, performance-testing

I've got protractor-perf working in my tests, and when I log the full set of metrics out, it seems to be missing some of the ones I'd expect from the Chrome timeline (and what browser perf says it collects here: https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf/wiki/Metrics)

Specifically, I'm looking for FunctionCall, and Layout - but they seem to be missing.

Also, there are metrics for Styles and Javascripts but they're returning 0 values (I know there's a tonne of both on the page - am I misunderstanding these values?).

I'm running this on the latest protractor-perf with Chrome 48 and chromedriver 2.21, and all looks to be working as far as I can tell.

These are the metrics I get results for (it's a pretty long list):

```
Styles
Javascript
fetchStart
domComplete
redirectEnd
LoadEventStart
navigationStart
requestStart
responseEnd
secureConnectionStart
domLoading
domInteractive
domainLookupEnd
domContentLoadedEventStart
loadEventEnd
connectEnd
responseStart
unloadEventStart
domContentLoadedEventEnd
connectStart
firstPaint
unloadEventEnd
domainLookupStart
loadTime
domReadyTime
readyStart
redirectTime
appcacheTime
unloadEventTime
domainLookupTime
connectTime
requestTime
initDomTreeTime
loadEventTime
NetworkJs
NetworkJs_avg
NetworkJs_max
NetworkJs_count
NetworkOther
NetworkOther_avg
NetworkOther_max
NetworkOther_count
NetworkImage
NetworkImage_avg
NetworkImage_max
NetworkImage_count
NetworkIframe
NetworkIframe_avg
NetworkIframe_max
NetworkIframe_count
NetworkCSS
NetworkCSS_avg
NetworkCSS_max
NetworkCSS_count
```

Comment: I implemented this tool not too long ago... quickly abandoned my efforts a few days later as I found there to be a _massive_ lack of documentation on this tool and the metrics =/